# setting end of the fullcalendar event overwrites start

Tags: fullcalendar, momentjs

When you drop external item on to fullcalendar it automatically sets start date of the event but end time is null. So what I want to do is set end time to 2h later.

```
eventReceive: function(event){
    event.end = event.start;
    console.log(event.start.format()); // 2014-12-14T07:00:00 
    event.end.add(2, 'h');
    console.log(event.start.format()); // 2014-12-14T09:00:00 
    ...
```

when ever I try to do that `event.start` is set to exact same time as `event.end`

**EDIT**
Solved by `forceEventDuration`, but still curious about why does it do that?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle as an example so that I can show you how you can change your code in order to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`event.start` is an `object`. You are passing the object reference, not the value. To see how this works in javascript execute this:

```
var x = {"a": 10}
var y = x
y["a"] = 5
console.log(x)
```

This will return `{"a": 5}` because you changed the referenced object. You would need to create a copy (clone) of the object first before you pass it.